# get errors from client post method in django testing

Tags: django, testing, post

Is there a quick way to get the errors from a form submission when using Client in a django test?

Here's a code snippet:

```
with open(good_path) as fp:
            data = {
                'account': account_id,
                'date': date,
                'file': fp
            }
            response = client.post(reverse('myapp:form-page'), data)
```

The page is not redirecting correctly (response=200) and I can see in `response.content` that there is an error being returned.

Is there a quick way to isolate the error? I was hoping for something like `response.errors`, similar to a forms instance.

Comment: add your `View` as well to question, where you are posting data

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming the underlying view uses a template to render its response, you can access the context of that template using `response.context`. So, for example, if your view does something like this:

```
form = MyForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    return redirect(...)
return render(request, 'template.html', {'form': form})
```

your test can access `response.context['form'].errors` to see the form errors.